# Spring Restful Service + Spring for android, missing parameter while uploading file

Tags: java, android, json, spring, rest

I've had fight with Spring restservice for 2 days and I can't get through file upload.

I my controller and its methods is based on guide http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

But I had many problems with that. First of all I had to include library: jackson-mapper-asl
because my request's were ALWAYS returning an error. I wonder why in Spring Webservice template project this library wasn't added.

Since I've added jackson-mapper-asl library my simple GET request were handled properly.
But when I implemented method that handles file upload as it was described in this guide it wouldn't work at all.

this is my Controller class and its method implementation:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controller")
public class GreetingsController {

@RequestMapping(value="/upload2", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload2(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("myfile") MultipartFile file){
    if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name + "-uploaded")));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
            return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name + "-uploaded !";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

this is my part of android code that makes a request:

```
final String serviceAddress3= "http://someaddress:8080/testappx2/controller/upload2";
String mb05 = sdcardMountPoint + "/DCIM/halfMB.jar";
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);           

FileSystemResource fsr = new FileSystemResource(mb05);
final LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
map.add("name", "superplik");
map.add("myfile", fsr);

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        Object result = restTemplate.postForObject(serviceAddress2, map, String.class);     
    }
});
t.start();
```

I use following libraries:

```
* spring-core 3.0.5.RELEASE
* spring-web 3.0.5.RELEASE
* spring-webmvc 3.0.5.RELEASE
* jackson-mapper-asl 1.9.13
```

I tried to make a POST request with SoapUI and directly from an Android mock APP. The only result I got was: `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request`
I decided to dug into my application server logs and I found out that my request is not "complete"

Request handle logs below:

```
16:09:46,029 TRACE [org.jboss.as.web.security] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Begin invoke, caller=null
16:09:46,030 TRACE [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6195db1d
16:09:46,032 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing POST request for [/testappx2/controller/upload]
16:09:46,034 TRACE [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping@16321271] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
16:09:46,035 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Mapping [/controller/upload] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [hello.GreetingsController@6ee8560d] and 2 interceptors
16:09:46,037 TRACE [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter@5769a85d]
16:09:46,039 DEBUG [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Set encoding to ISO-8859-1
16:09:46,040 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Resolving exception from handler [hello.GreetingsController@6ee8560d]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'name' is not present
16:09:46,043 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Resolving exception from handler [hello.GreetingsController@6ee8560d]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'name' is not present
16:09:46,045 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Resolving exception from handler [hello.GreetingsController@6ee8560d]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'name' is not present
16:09:46,047 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
16:09:46,048 TRACE [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6195db1d
16:09:46,049 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Successfully completed request
16:09:46,050 TRACE [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/testappx2/controller/upload]; client=[172.16.241.58]; method=[POST]; servlet=[mvc-dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[20ms]; status=[OK]
16:09:46,051 TRACE [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/testappx2/controller/upload]; client=[172.16.241.58]; method=[POST]; servlet=[mvc-dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[20ms]; status=[OK]
16:09:46,052 TRACE [org.jboss.as.web.security] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) End invoke, caller=null
16:09:46,052 TRACE [org.jboss.security.SecurityRolesAssociation] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Setting threadlocal:null
16:09:46,052 TRACE [org.jboss.jca.core.api.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) popped object: org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.CachedConnectionManagerSetupProcessor$CachedConnectionManagerSetupAction@4bae320
```

Appserver says that "name" parameter was not passed: `[hello.GreetingsController@6ee8560d]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'name' is not present`

The fun thing is (what I have accidentally discovered) that when I omit adding "myfile" parameter to LinkedMultiValueMap It founds it, parses it and then it gets into body of the method.

Appserver log:

```
16:52:29,391 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Resolving exception from handler [hello.GreetingsController@788a7860]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'myfile' is not present
16:52:29,391 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Resolving exception from handler [hello.GreetingsController@788a7860]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'myfile' is not present
16:52:29,392 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
16:52:29,393 TRACE [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@8f22ae
16:52:29,393 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Successfully completed request
16:52:29,394 TRACE [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/testappx3/controller/upload2]; client=[172.16.241.58]; method=[POST]; servlet=[mvc-dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[35ms]; status=[OK]
16:52:29,394 TRACE [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/testappx3/controller/upload2]; client=[172.16.241.58]; method=[POST]; servlet=[mvc-dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[35ms]; status=[OK]
16:52:29,395 TRACE [org.jboss.as.web.security] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) End invoke, caller=null
```

Now appserver says there's no "myfile" parameter.

I thought there's something wrong with having declared more than 1 `RequestParameter` in this method. But tried it with multiple `String` `RequestParameters` and that seems to work fine.

What am I doing wrong? Am I leprous or smth?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean this one? http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/
I don't like to say that, but - it works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this problem. Somewhere I read, that I need to declare magic bean called `multipartResolver` in one of my spring context files(I'm not even sure if this is context file, these all spring things seem new to me) in my case that was `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file

Additional bean entry I had to add.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000000" />
</bean>
```

Adding this bean also caused unability to deploy this application in my `JBoss AS 7.1` throwing such exception:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory`

I googled this class and I found out that it is part of `commons-fileupload` library.
Dependency from maven repository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency allowed me to deploy and enable application in `JBoss AS 7.1`.

However that wasn't end of my battle. Then I moved forward to test this service. Unfortunately another servlet exception was thrown this time cause by:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream`

Again I googled it and found out that desired class is part of library `commons-io` by apache

dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The END.
PS. The sad thing is, that I was using a guide from `Spring` official site, and there wasn't  mentioned neither about additional required libraries nor about `mutlipartResolver` bean. Which I found a little ridiculous...

Thanks even for reading all of this stuff :)